# JSTL: check if a string is empty

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to test in JSTL if a session attribute is empty. However the attribute is empty JSTL sees it as a non-empty attribute.

This is the hardcode I'm trying to replace with JSTL. This code is working correctly:

```JSP
<% if (request.getAttribute("error") != null) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Oh snap, something's wrong, maybe the following error could help you out?<br /></strong>
        <%= request.getAttribute("error")%>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

This is how I replaced it with JSTL. When checked, the error-attribute is not empty, however it is empty.

```JSP
<c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.error}">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Oh snap, something's wrong, maybe the following error could help you out?<br /></strong>
        <c:out value="${sessionScope.error}" />
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Comment: have you added jstl library

Comment: have you imported jstl tag in page **<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>**

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I was troubleshooting this for more than an hour. Thanks :)

Comment: @gyanu Edit your post and add the actual solution

Comment: i did it. I hope my answer will be accepted.Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the JSTL library and declare the core taglib:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

The JSTL equivalent of

```
<% if (request.getAttribute("error") != null) { %>
```

is

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
```

Comment: OP is doing in the same way.

Comment: Tried to remove the requestScope, but same problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm trying to test in JSTL if a `session attribute` is empty**

You have to check in *session scope* not in *request scope*.

It should be

```
<c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.error}">
```

instead of

```
<c:if test="${not empty requestScope.error}">
```

---

If you are not sure about the scope then use without scope that will look in all scope from bottom to top (page, request, session then finally in application)

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
```

Comment: Changed, same problem persists. I also tried to remove the scope, not working either. I'm absolutely sure the attribute is empty because I left the old code active and that code is not generating anything.

Comment: Look at my edited post. Share the code where are you setting the attribute. May be `error` is not the correct attribute name.

Comment: `${not empty null}` and `${not empty ""}` return `false`.

Comment: The problem is solved. <shame>I forgot to add the library.</shame>. I was troubleshooting this for more than an hour. Thanks for your help, though. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Oh no silly mistake. I was not expecting this from you.